# How to display a pop up message in laravel before redirecting to login page when the session expires?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I wanted to display a pop-up message when the session timeout or expires, I change the session_lifetime value in the `.env` file and under the session.php and tried displaying the message in the authenticate.php, I provided the sample below:

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {

        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            echo "<script>alert('hello')</script>";
            exit();
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

the case is whenever I do this, it won't redirect in the login page anymore. because of the exit(), but when I remove the exit function it won't display the alert and just continue to redirect in the login page.

Comment: You can try with showing alert with box having `Ok` button and whenever user clicks on it they will be redirected to login page, make sure there should be no provision to close the popup.

Answer (score 0):

To put HTML inside some files that are *not* views is a very bad practice, and you should avoid it.

You can set a message in your session wrapper and display it in the page you are redirecting to

```
session()->flash('error', 'Session expired');
return route('login');
```